# Which AES library/API for unmanaged C(++) and C# compatible?

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, aes

I have a server application written in C# and the clients written in ANSI C++ and I need to exchange encrypted data between them (over network). I'd prefer symetric encryption for this project and it should work within the two languages. I'd be happy enough with a small lib which is compatible to the .NET built-in encryption classes. Thanks.

**Note:** would be great if it's a static library!

Comment: I found `mcrypt` to be a nice C library which is easily wrapped for C++.

Comment: Thank you. Anyone has experience with the Crypto++ library? I don't need this many features...

Comment: The *S* in AES stands for *Standard* - i.e. every implementation should be compatible to every other one (just make sure you use the same modes of operations and padding modes).

Answer (score 0):

HAve you looked over [crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/)? It's not very small, but it should be OK to link against it.

Comment: Yes I did and I was a bit skeptic if it isn't too overblown for my needs. So you worked with it and it's good?